# create XML from flowchart

Tags: xml

I try to create XML from a simple flowchart but i have some problem 
my flowchart is this :
[image]

and XML code i write is this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start>
    <datainput>
        <element>read N</element>
    </datainput>
    <seq1>
        <element>M =1</element>
        <element>F =1</element>
    </seq1>
    <loop>
        <seq2>
            <element>F = F*M</element>
        </seq2>
        <desc>
            <element>IS M=N?</element>
        </desc>
        <seq3>
            <element>M = M+1</element>
        </seq3>
    </loop>
    <dataout>
        <element>PRINT F</element>
    </dataout>
</start>
```

I think is not good coding

Can i delete `<element>` tag?

are another way for show loop in programm?

Comment: It is strange all the items are part of `start`. Most models probably work with a *node-relation model.* Where you enumerate all nodes together with some of their attributes. And a list of relations (arrows) between the components.

Comment: @CommuSoft can you write an example?